# How to make sure a function is not executed until Ext.FormPanel has successfully submitted its data?

Tags: javascript, extjs, callback

I have an Ext.FormPanel which has a `Save` button which is supposed to do two things in this order: **(1) post** the data, **(2) go back** to the page from where it was called.

```
buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
        handler: function() {
            if(panel_form.getForm().isValid()){
                panel_form.getForm().getEl().dom.action = 'backend/page/blocks/edit_positioned_post/17.html';
                panel_form.getForm().getEl().dom.method = 'POST';
                panel_form.getForm().submit(); //FIRST POST DATA
                replace_region_with_uri_content('/backend/page'); //THEN GO BACK
            } else {
                Ext.Msg.minWidth = 360;
                Ext.Msg.alert('Invalid Form', 'Some fields are invalid, please correct.');
            }
        }
    },{
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: function(){
            replace_region_with_uri_content('/backend/page');
        }
    }]
```

However what **actually happens** is backwards, as I can see in Firebug, i.e. it **(1) goes back**, and **(2) posts** the data, which leads to the situation that the grid that it returns to **does not show the updated data**.

[image]

**How can I force it to execute `replace_region_with_uri_content()` only after `panel_form.getForm().submit()` is completed, i.e. by sending the first function as a callback of the second?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, you can add a "success function" into the parameter array of submit() like this:

```
    buttons: [{
            text: 'Save',
            handler: function() {
                if(panel_form.getForm().isValid()){
                    panel_form.getForm().getEl().dom.action = 'backend/page/blocks/edit_positioned_post/17.html';
                    panel_form.getForm().getEl().dom.method = 'POST';
                    panel_form.getForm().submit({
                        success : function(form, action) {
                            replace_region_with_uri_content('/backend/page');
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    Ext.Msg.minWidth = 360;
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Invalid Form', 'Some fields are invalid, please correct.');
                }
            }
        },{
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: function(){
                replace_region_with_uri_content('/backend/page');
            }
        }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add an event to the form, check out the actioncomplete event for BasicForm -

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.BasicForm

You should only redirect here as once this event executes your form should have submitted.